# Attempting to Deploy my Rails app to Heroku: ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my rails app to Heroku and I'm running into some error messages that I can't quite make sense of. Does anyone have an idea as to how to resolve this?

Do I need to update my webpacker? This is my first time deploying a Rails app to Heroku so I'm a bit lost as to how best to resolve this issue. Much thanks!

```
   Running: rake assets:precompile
   yarn install v1.22.4
   info No lockfile found.
   [1/4] Resolving packages...
   warning @rails/webpacker > node-sass > request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
   warning @rails/webpacker > node-sass > node-gyp > request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
   warning @rails/webpacker > node-sass > request > har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
   warning @rails/webpacker > webpack > watchpack > watchpack-chokidar2 > chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
   warning @rails/webpacker > webpack > watchpack > watchpack-chokidar2 > chokidar > fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
   warning @rails/webpacker > webpack > micromatch > snapdragon > source-map-resolve > urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
   warning @rails/webpacker > webpack > micromatch > snapdragon > source-map-resolve > resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
   warning webpack-dev-server > chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
   [2/4] Fetching packages...
   info fsevents@2.3.2: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
   info "fsevents@2.3.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
   info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
   info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
   [3/4] Linking dependencies...
   warning " > webpack-dev-server@3.11.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0".
   warning "webpack-dev-server > webpack-dev-middleware@3.7.3" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0".
   [4/4] Building fresh packages...
   Done in 41.58s.
   I, [2021-04-22T21:10:55.960610 #1490]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_44a69be4/public/assets/manifest-b4bf6e57a53c2bdb55b8998cc94cd00883793c1c37c5e5aea3ef6749b4f6d92b.js
   I, [2021-04-22T21:10:55.961031 #1490]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_44a69be4/public/assets/manifest-b4bf6e57a53c2bdb55b8998cc94cd00883793c1c37c5e5aea3ef6749b4f6d92b.js.gz
   I, [2021-04-22T21:10:55.961290 #1490]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_44a69be4/public/assets/application-90fcf18e206cb5b1aed2303a51959b0182f1b2e83030a6dbf244ae423904a00a.css
   I, [2021-04-22T21:10:55.961474 #1490]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_44a69be4/public/assets/application-90fcf18e206cb5b1aed2303a51959b0182f1b2e83030a6dbf244ae423904a00a.css.gz
   I, [2021-04-22T21:10:55.961709 #1490]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_44a69be4/public/assets/bakers_percentages-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.css
   I, [2021-04-22T21:10:55.961888 #1490]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_44a69be4/public/assets/bakers_percentages-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.css.gz
   I, [2021-04-22T21:10:55.962350 #1490]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_44a69be4/public/assets/bakes-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.css
   I, [2021-04-22T21:10:55.962522 #1490]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_44a69be4/public/assets/bakes-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.css.gz
   I, [2021-04-22T21:10:55.962902 #1490]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_44a69be4/public/assets/bookmarks-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.css
   I, [2021-04-22T21:10:55.963207 #1490]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_44a69be4/public/assets/bookmarks-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.css.gz
   I, [2021-04-22T21:10:55.964744 #1490]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_44a69be4/public/assets/comments-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.css
   I, [2021-04-22T21:10:55.965213 #1490]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_44a69be4/public/assets/comments-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.css.gz
   I, [2021-04-22T21:10:55.965581 #1490]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_44a69be4/public/assets/ingredients-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.css
   I, [2021-04-22T21:10:55.965921 #1490]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_44a69be4/public/assets/ingredients-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.css.gz
   I, [2021-04-22T21:10:55.966312 #1490]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_44a69be4/public/assets/likes-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.css
   I, [2021-04-22T21:10:55.966682 #1490]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_44a69be4/public/assets/likes-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.css.gz
   I, [2021-04-22T21:10:55.967157 #1490]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_44a69be4/public/assets/posts-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.css
   I, [2021-04-22T21:10:55.967445 #1490]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_44a69be4/public/assets/posts-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.css.gz
   I, [2021-04-22T21:10:55.967826 #1490]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_44a69be4/public/assets/recipes-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.css
   I, [2021-04-22T21:10:55.968116 #1490]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_44a69be4/public/assets/recipes-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.css.gz
   I, [2021-04-22T21:10:55.968366 #1490]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_44a69be4/public/assets/sessions-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.css
   I, [2021-04-22T21:10:55.968652 #1490]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_44a69be4/public/assets/sessions-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.css.gz
   I, [2021-04-22T21:10:55.969055 #1490]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_44a69be4/public/assets/steps-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.css
   I, [2021-04-22T21:10:55.969231 #1490]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_44a69be4/public/assets/steps-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.css.gz
   I, [2021-04-22T21:10:55.969479 #1490]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_44a69be4/public/assets/users-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.css
   I, [2021-04-22T21:10:55.969652 #1490]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_44a69be4/public/assets/users-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.css.gz
   I, [2021-04-22T21:10:55.969896 #1490]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_44a69be4/public/assets/welcome-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.css
   I, [2021-04-22T21:10:55.970071 #1490]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_44a69be4/public/assets/welcome-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.css.gz
   Compiling...
   Compilation failed:
   ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stylesheets/application' in '/tmp/build_44a69be4/app/javascript/packs'
       at /tmp/build_44a69be4/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:925:10
       at /tmp/build_44a69be4/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:401:22
       at /tmp/build_44a69be4/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:130:21
       at /tmp/build_44a69be4/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:224:22
       at /tmp/build_44a69be4/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2830:7
       at /tmp/build_44a69be4/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:6877:13
       at /tmp/build_44a69be4/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:214:25
       at /tmp/build_44a69be4/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:213:14
       at /tmp/build_44a69be4/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
       at eval (eval at create (/tmp/build_44a69be4/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
       at /tmp/build_44a69be4/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/UnsafeCachePlugin.js:44:7
       at /tmp/build_44a69be4/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
       at eval (eval at create (/tmp/build_44a69be4/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
       at /tmp/build_44a69be4/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
       at eval (eval at create (/tmp/build_44a69be4/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:25:1)
       at /tmp/build_44a69be4/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/DescriptionFilePlugin.js:67:43
       at /tmp/build_44a69be4/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
       at eval (eval at create (/tmp/build_44a69be4/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:41:1)
       at /tmp/build_44a69be4/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/ModuleKindPlugin.js:30:40
       at /tmp/build_44a69be4/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
       at eval (eval at create (/tmp/build_44a69be4/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
       at /tmp/build_44a69be4/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
       at eval (eval at create (/tmp/build_44a69be4/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:14:1)
       at /tmp/build_44a69be4/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/forEachBail.js:30:14
       at /tmp/build_44a69be4/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
       at eval (eval at create (/tmp/build_44a69be4/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
       at /tmp/build_44a69be4/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/UnsafeCachePlugin.js:44:7
       at /tmp/build_44a69be4/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
       at eval (eval at create (/tmp/build_44a69be4/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:13:1)
       at /tmp/build_44a69be4/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
       at eval (eval at create (/tmp/build_44a69be4/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:25:1)
       at /tmp/build_44a69be4/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/DescriptionFilePlugin.js:67:43
       at /tmp/build_44a69be4/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
       at eval (eval at create (/tmp/build_44a69be4/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:14:1)
       at /tmp/build_44a69be4/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/RootPlugin.js:37:38
       at _next42 (eval at create (/tmp/build_44a69be4/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
   resolve 'stylesheets/application' in '/tmp/build_44a69be4/app/javascript/packs'
     Parsed request is a module
     using description file: /tmp/build_44a69be4/package.json (relative path: ./app/javascript/packs)
       Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
       resolve as module
         looking for modules in /tmp/build_44a69be4/app/javascript
           using description file: /tmp/build_44a69be4/package.json (relative path: ./app/javascript)
             Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
             using description file: /tmp/build_44a69be4/package.json (relative path: ./app/javascript/stylesheets/application)
               no extension
                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                 /tmp/build_44a69be4/app/javascript/stylesheets/application doesn't exist
               .mjs
                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                 /tmp/build_44a69be4/app/javascript/stylesheets/application.mjs doesn't exist
               .js
                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                 /tmp/build_44a69be4/app/javascript/stylesheets/application.js doesn't exist
               .sass
                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                 /tmp/build_44a69be4/app/javascript/stylesheets/application.sass doesn't exist
               .scss
                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                 /tmp/build_44a69be4/app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss doesn't exist
               .css
                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                 /tmp/build_44a69be4/app/javascript/stylesheets/application.css doesn't exist
               .module.sass
                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                 /tmp/build_44a69be4/app/javascript/stylesheets/application.module.sass doesn't exist
               .module.scss
                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                 /tmp/build_44a69be4/app/javascript/stylesheets/application.module.scss doesn't exist
               .module.css
                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                 /tmp/build_44a69be4/app/javascript/stylesheets/application.module.css doesn't exist
               .png
                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                 /tmp/build_44a69be4/app/javascript/stylesheets/application.png doesn't exist
               .svg
                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                 /tmp/build_44a69be4/app/javascript/stylesheets/application.svg doesn't exist
               .gif
                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                 /tmp/build_44a69be4/app/javascript/stylesheets/application.gif doesn't exist
               .jpeg
                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                 /tmp/build_44a69be4/app/javascript/stylesheets/application.jpeg doesn't exist
               .jpg
                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                 /tmp/build_44a69be4/app/javascript/stylesheets/application.jpg doesn't exist
               as directory
                 /tmp/build_44a69be4/app/javascript/stylesheets/application doesn't exist
         /tmp/build_44a69be4/app/javascript/packs/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
         /tmp/build_44a69be4/app/javascript/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
         /tmp/build_44a69be4/app/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
         /tmp/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
         /node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
         looking for modules in /tmp/build_44a69be4/node_modules
           using description file: /tmp/build_44a69be4/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
             Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
             using description file: /tmp/build_44a69be4/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/stylesheets/application)
               no extension
                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                 /tmp/build_44a69be4/node_modules/stylesheets/application doesn't exist
               .mjs
                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                 /tmp/build_44a69be4/node_modules/stylesheets/application.mjs doesn't exist
               .js
                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                 /tmp/build_44a69be4/node_modules/stylesheets/application.js doesn't exist
               .sass
                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                 /tmp/build_44a69be4/node_modules/stylesheets/application.sass doesn't exist
               .scss
                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                 /tmp/build_44a69be4/node_modules/stylesheets/application.scss doesn't exist
               .css
                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                 /tmp/build_44a69be4/node_modules/stylesheets/application.css doesn't exist
               .module.sass
                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                 /tmp/build_44a69be4/node_modules/stylesheets/application.module.sass doesn't exist
               .module.scss
                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                 /tmp/build_44a69be4/node_modules/stylesheets/application.module.scss doesn't exist
               .module.css
                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                 /tmp/build_44a69be4/node_modules/stylesheets/application.module.css doesn't exist
               .png
                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                 /tmp/build_44a69be4/node_modules/stylesheets/application.png doesn't exist
               .svg
                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                 /tmp/build_44a69be4/node_modules/stylesheets/application.svg doesn't exist
               .gif
                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                 /tmp/build_44a69be4/node_modules/stylesheets/application.gif doesn't exist
               .jpeg
                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                 /tmp/build_44a69be4/node_modules/stylesheets/application.jpeg doesn't exist
               .jpg
                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                 /tmp/build_44a69be4/node_modules/stylesheets/application.jpg doesn't exist
               as directory
                 /tmp/build_44a69be4/node_modules/stylesheets/application doesn't exist
!
!     Precompiling assets failed.
!
!     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
!     Push failed
```

Comment: You tried to do import stylesheets/application file in your packs. But not found your stylesheets/application file into the correct path

Comment: Yup, that was it!

Idk why I was importing the stylesheet there anyway. I think it was back when I tried to install bulma CSS using yarn.

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are your app stylesheets located?  I think your clue is here:

ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stylesheets/application' in '/tmp/build_44a69be4/app/javascript/packs'

Webpacker is looking for 'stylesheets/application.scss' in the /app/javascript/packs directory and can't find it.